# Netbeans project setup Ruby

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans-6.9, ruby-1.9

I'm new to Ruby and how projects are set up. I am using Netbeans IDE and in the GUI there is a "Source Folder" but this resides at `~/NetBeansWorkspace/ProjectName/lib` rather than a `src` folder. Is this the convention in Ruby? If not how do I get Netbeans to put my files under a `src` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I know that in Rails all the applications are put in a folder that is named whatever you name the project.  Inside the folder is all the resources for the application.  The lib folder should contain "additional" code for your application.